# How to print with landscape orientation in PyQt5?

Tags: python, printing, pyqt5, orientation, landscape

How can I modify this code to print automatically with, or to set default settings to landscape orientation?

I'm new to PyQt5. Trying to make an app with printing function. I copy+pasted this code from the internet but it's default setting is portrait orientation. It would be important to print with landscape orientation automatically.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtPrintSupport, QtGui

class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setWindowTitle(self.tr('Document Printer'))
        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(200, 5, self)

        for row in range(self.table.rowCount()):
            for col in range(self.table.columnCount()):
                item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem('(%d, %d)' % (row, col))
                item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
                self.table.setItem(row, col, item)
        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(
            'SKU #|NAME|DESCRIPTION|QUANTITY|PRICE'.split('|'))
        self.buttonPrint = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Print', self)
        self.buttonPrint.clicked.connect(self.handlePrint)
        self.buttonPreview = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Preview', self)
        self.buttonPreview.clicked.connect(self.handlePreview)
        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.table, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        layout.addWidget(self.buttonPrint, 1, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.buttonPreview, 1, 1)

    def handlePrint(self):
        dialog = QtPrintSupport.QPrintDialog()
        if dialog.exec_() == QtWidgets.QDialog.Accepted:
            self.handlePaintRequest(dialog.printer())

    def handlePreview(self):
        dialog = QtPrintSupport.QPrintPreviewDialog()
        dialog.paintRequested.connect(self.handlePaintRequest)

        dialog.exec_()

    def handlePaintRequest(self, printer):
        document = self.makeTableDocument()
        document.print_(printer)

    def makeTableDocument(self):
        document = QtGui.QTextDocument()
        cursor = QtGui.QTextCursor(document)
        rows = self.table.rowCount()
        columns = self.table.columnCount()
        table = cursor.insertTable(rows + 1, columns)
        format = table.format()
        format.setHeaderRowCount(1)
        table.setFormat(format)
        format = cursor.blockCharFormat()
        format.setFontWeight(QtGui.QFont.Bold)
        for column in range(columns):
            cursor.setCharFormat(format)
            cursor.insertText(
                self.table.horizontalHeaderItem(column).text())
            cursor.movePosition(QtGui.QTextCursor.NextCell)
        for row in range(rows):
            for column in range(columns):
                cursor.insertText(
                    self.table.item(row, column).text())
                cursor.movePosition(QtGui.QTextCursor.NextCell)
        return document

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.resize(640, 480)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Do anyone have any idea? Or have a snippet of code to landscape printing in pyqt5? Thank You!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**QPrinter::Orientation**

This enum type (not to be confused with Orientation) is used to specify each page's orientation.

```
Constant          Value      Description
QPrinter::Portrait  0   the page's height is greater than its width.
QPrinter::Landscape 1   the page's width is greater than its height.

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtPrintSupport, QtGui

class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setWindowTitle(self.tr('Document Printer'))
        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(200, 5, self)

        for row in range(self.table.rowCount()):
            for col in range(self.table.columnCount()):
                item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem('(%d, %d)' % (row, col))
                item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
                self.table.setItem(row, col, item)
        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(
            'SKU #|NAME|DESCRIPTION|QUANTITY|PRICE'.split('|'))
        self.buttonPrint = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Print', self)
        self.buttonPrint.clicked.connect(self.handlePrint)
        self.buttonPreview = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Preview', self)
        self.buttonPreview.clicked.connect(self.handlePreview)
        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.table, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        layout.addWidget(self.buttonPrint, 1, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.buttonPreview, 1, 1)

    def handlePrint(self):
        dialog = QtPrintSupport.QPrintDialog()
        if dialog.exec_() == QtWidgets.QDialog.Accepted:
            self.handlePaintRequest(dialog.printer())

    def handlePreview(self):
        dialog = QtPrintSupport.QPrintPreviewDialog()
        dialog.paintRequested.connect(self.handlePaintRequest)

        dialog.exec_()

    def handlePaintRequest(self, printer):

        print("printer --> ", printer.orientation())
        printer.setOrientation(QtPrintSupport.QPrinter.Landscape)     # <------------
        print("printer 2--> ", printer.orientation())

        document = self.makeTableDocument()
        document.print_(printer)

    def makeTableDocument(self):
        document = QtGui.QTextDocument()
        cursor = QtGui.QTextCursor(document)
        rows = self.table.rowCount()
        columns = self.table.columnCount()
        table = cursor.insertTable(rows + 1, columns)
        format = table.format()
        format.setHeaderRowCount(1)
        table.setFormat(format)
        format = cursor.blockCharFormat()
        format.setFontWeight(QtGui.QFont.Bold)
        for column in range(columns):
            cursor.setCharFormat(format)
            cursor.insertText(
                self.table.horizontalHeaderItem(column).text())
            cursor.movePosition(QtGui.QTextCursor.NextCell)
        for row in range(rows):
            for column in range(columns):
                cursor.insertText(
                    self.table.item(row, column).text())
                cursor.movePosition(QtGui.QTextCursor.NextCell)
        return document

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.resize(640, 480)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Thank You!