# Python 3 PyQt5 QtPrintSupport Quick Print (without showing dialog)

Tags: python, pyqt5

Good morning,
I am trying to make a "quick print" function for my application. Without entering lots of code here, I have modified the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54600127/how-to-print-with-landscape-orientation-in-pyqt5)

There are two functions:

```
def handlePrint(self):


def handlePreview(self):
```

But, how can I make a function to just print without a preview or dialog? Eg.

```
def handleQuickPrint(self):
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both methods basically create a QPrinter based on the configuration of the dialog, so the solution is to create a QPrinter and set those properties:

```py
def handleQuickPrint(self):
    printer = QtPrintSupport.QPrinter()
    printer.setOutputFileName("test.pdf")
    self.handlePaintRequest(printer)
```